# How to pull in another forked branch of my upstream into my forked branch?

Tags: git

I have forked a fork `my_fork` from an upstream master. Later, another developer forked the upstream to his own fork `his_fork`, and created a `bug_fix_branch` off it. I want to pull that bug fix into `my_fork`.

```
upstream master ===========================>
                   \       \
                    \       \==============> his_fork
                     \           \=========> bug_fix_branch
                      \              |
                       \             | How to do this?
                        \            V 
                         \=================> my_fork
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
git checkout my_fork

# counting revisions in bug_fix_branch... say it's 3 revisions:
git cherry-pick bug_fix_branch~3..bug_fix_branch
# or not counting revisions in bug_fix_branch
git cherry-pick ^his_fork bug_fix_branch
```